# Portfolio optimization sensitivity in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, solver, portfolio

I need some help in VBA and excel

I cant get the VBA code to print out the different asset weights. The only thing it returns is numbers from -1 to 1 in AG. Can anyone please help me with this code?

This is my code:

```
' This sub creates 6 rows of weighted data, and a 7th row of the percentage used. This will allow for relative low-effort graphing.
Sub ExpRet()
    'Define in- and output ranges
    Row1 = Range("AA2:DX8").Row
    Column1 = Range("AA2:DX8").Column
    Row2 = Range("R3:W3").Row
    Column2 = Range("R3:W3").Column
    
    ' Run for all six assets
    For assetCounter = 1 To 6
        ' Set the mean to the current asset's Mean
        AX = Cells(Row2, Column2 - 1 + assetCounter).Value
        sensitivityCounter = 1 'makes sure the sensitivityCounter equals one
        
        ' Run for 102 instances, covering the range from -100% to +100%
        For sensitivityCounter = 1 To 101
            Cells(Row2, Column2 - 1 + assetCounter).Value = AX * 0.02 * (sensitivityCounter - 1)
            
            'Run Solver
            SolverReset
            SolverOptions AssumeNonNeg:=True
            SolverAdd CellRef:=("S20:S25"), Relation:=1, Formulatext:="0.25"
            SolverAdd CellRef:=("S20:S25"), Relation:=3, Formulatext:="0"
            SolverAdd CellRef:=("S26"), Relation:=2, Formulatext:="1"
            SolverOk SetCell:=("S33"), MaxMinVal:=1, ByChange:="S20:S25"
            SolverSolve (True)
            SolverFinish
            
            'Print current asset's Weight in output, and the current % value
            If assetCounter = 1 Then
                Cells(Row1 - 1 + sensitivityCounter, Column1).Value = Range("AA2:DX2").Value
                Cells(Row1 - 1 + sensitivityCounter, Column1 + 6).Value = (0.02 * (sensitivityCounter - 1) - 1)
            ElseIf assetCounter = 2 Then
                Cells(Row1 - 1 + sensitivityCounter, Column1 + 1).Value = Range("AA3:DX3").Value
            ElseIf assetCounter = 3 Then
                Cells(Row1 - 1 + sensitivityCounter, Column1 + 2).Value = Range("AA4:DX4").Value
            ElseIf assetCounter = 4 Then
                Cells(Row1 - 1 + sensitivityCounter, Column1 + 3).Value = Range("AA5:DX5").Value
            ElseIf assetCounter = 5 Then
                Cells(Row1 - 1 + sensitivityCounter, Column1 + 4).Value = Range("AA6:DX6").Value
            ElseIf assetCounter = 6 Then
                Cells(Row1 - 1 + sensitivityCounter, Column1 + 5).Value = Range("AA7:DX7").Value
            End If
        Next sensitivityCounter
        
        'Resets the mean value back to the Original for the current Asset before further calculations
        Cells(Row2, Column2 - 1 + assetCounter).Value = AX
    Next assetCounter
End Sub
```

[image]

I am expecting a sensitivity that returns the allocation weight in each asset when relative expected return change.